# prometheus query returns inconsistent results

Tags: api, prometheus

I have some data in prometheus that looks like this: [image: s]

I have a job that runs every 2 minutes on a server and pushes values to prometheus' pushgateway and that's how it reaches prometheus. Now im trying to query this data with the HTTP API and I'm noticing that it returns inconsistent results, it either returns the data I expect to see or it doesnt return anything at all.

My queries are [range queries](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#range-queries) where for example start = now() - 1w and end = now. The problem seems to show when I use high values for the step/resolution. The only step that seems to work all of the time is `5m`. When I try `10m` sometimes it works but usually it doesnt. I'm guessing this depends on the time I send the request (maybe when I use the current time it breaks something).

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

try to set the step as the size of the duration in the []. eg. if your query look like that: http_requests_total{job="prometheus"}[5m], use step = 5m.
if you want 10m change the duration and the step to 10m.